# The task scheduler does not work correctly when placed on a remote stand. Java Spring @Scheduled

Tags: java, spring

Actually, the description of the problem itself is in the title.
When I start the server on the local computer, the scheduler works correctly. When I place an application on a remote stand, it does not work.
I refer to the database, which is located remotely in both cases.

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 * * * *")
@SchedulerLock(name = "resourcePoolPredictionCalculate", lockAtMostFor = "30m", lockAtLeastFor = "30m")
public void refresh() {
    LocalDateTime start = LocalDateTime.now();
    repository.procResourcePoolPrepare();
    repository.procResourcePoolUpdate();
    log.info("[ResourcePoolPredictionTask] start at "+ start+" and lasted "+ ChronoUnit.SECONDS.between(start,LocalDateTime.now())+" seconds");
}
```

Sometimes nothing happens at all. Sometimes it starts up once an hour (as it should).
What could be such a different difference between the behavior on the local and remote stand?

Logs are below:

```
org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:448) ~[spring-orm-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.startTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:400) ~[spring-tx-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373) ~[spring-tx-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:573) ~[spring-tx-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:361) ~[spring-tx-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:118) ~[spring-tx-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:178) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.1.RELEASE]
```

Comment: Did you remmember to put `@EnableScheduling` in some @Configuration file?
Can you paste the startup logs from the remote machine here?

Also please not this:
"If any execution of the task encounters an exception, subsequent executions are suppressed."

You can try putting the LOG at the first step of the process. It seems to me that there is some exception problem here.

Comment: Thank You @Rafael for your answer, I'll try to put logging at the first step of method. 
The assembly of our project is carried out every night and I can only get the logs tomorrow, if possible. Since today there were no mistakes at all. But the scheduler did not start either.

Comment: Dear @Rafael I've updated the post by attaching logs.

Comment: `Unable to acquire JDBC Connection` ...!

Comment: [tag:spring] only or [booted][tag:spring-boot]??

Comment: @xerx593 I see the exception, but it happens only on one version of our stands ( Yes, Spring-boot

Comment: "stand" you mean like "dev, int, prod,...uat" ??or one machine? ..but i am confused by the word: "environment"!? ;)

Comment: spring-boot: read/study [this(Ext Config)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config), please ..so something in your "stand" has wrong credentials/url or network issues! (apart from spring ..maybe there are more hints in the stacktrace..?)

Comment: @xerx593 Yes, I mean dev, prod and so on. The credential seems to look proper. Thank You a lot for your answer. There is nothing left but to double-check everything.

Comment: in the [paragraph](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config) there are **14** possible locations, ordered by priority, where property can come from ... you checked all?? In cloud/container: they are often set via env-variable(5.) or command line argument (11).

Comment: Cool. We are on a good path. We now know whats the underlying problem: Your repository is unable to acquire a JDBC connection. Now this might happen by a variety of reasons. The first would be to MAKE SURE your creds are correctly setted ... but I guess you already did that. Another option would be that the JDBC connection pool is exhausted, or database is blocking new connections. This is not common but it's possible. On the other hand I am not familiar with "SchedulerLock" but I think the "lockAtMostFor" params are not correctly set.